# Is image dimensions really needed?

Tags: javascript, photoswipe

I've got an issue with the required image dimensions in the new Photoswipe. 
The CMS I use can't supply the image dimensions so that I can add the attribute data-size="" to my A tags.

Is there any way to avoid having to supply the image dimensions?

Comment: For now there are no plans on making version that doesn't require image dimensions, as it'll make PhotoSwipe simple slideshow script without zoom, progressive loading etc. Refer to http://photoswipe.com/documentation/faq.html#image-size

Answer (score 0):

Check this jQuery plugin I wrote. Very easy to use and you don't have to define image dimensions.

https://ergec.github.io/jQuery-for-PhotoSwipe/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").jqPhotoSwipe();
});
```